# How to get form from dynamic CDKPortalComponent

Tags: angular, typescript, ncurses-cdk

I have a cdkportal component that is created dynamically from about 5 different Components. They are added to a modal dialog. I need to know if the forms in these child components are valid and if they are not valid the a button on the parent will be disabled.

How can I get the forms and their validity?

This is in the parent.html

```
<div class="steps-content">
    <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="componentPortal" (attached)=portalAttached($event)>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
    <button  nz-button (click)="pre(); $event.preventDefault()" [disabled]="current == 0 || processing" *ngIf="current < 4">
        <span nz-icon nzType="left"></span>
        Previous        
    </button>
    <button nz-button [disabled] = CHILDFORM.Invalid>   <---------- I need to set here
        Next
        <span nz-icon nzType="right"></span>
    </button>
```

This is the parent.ts

```
changeContent(): void {
      switch (this.current) {
        case 0: {
          this.index = 'First-content';
          this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(AssessmentCompanyFormComponent);
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
        break;
        }
        case 1: {
          this.index = 'Second-content';
          this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(AssessmentLocationFormComponent);
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          break;
        }
        case 2: {
          this.index = 'third-content';
          this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(AssessmentJobsFormComponent);
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          break;
        }
        case 3:{
            this.index = 'fourth-content';
            this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(AssessmentReviewSubmitComponent);
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            this.index = 'fifth-content';
            this.componentPortal = new ComponentPortal(AssessmentSubmitComponent);
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
            break;
        }
        default: {
          this.index = 'error';
        }
      }
    }

portalAttached(_ref: CdkPortalOutletAttachedRef){
         this.ref = _ref as ComponentRef<any>;
         this.ref.instance.model = this.model; 
         this.ref.instance.assessmentOutput.subscribe(d =>{
          this.goToPage(d);
      })            
    }
```

here is the child of one of the components from above

```
export class AssessmentCompanyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  public validateForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
```

So basically anytime that validateForm has an invalid control I want the parent to know and keep that submit button disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to [statusChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#statusChanges) of the formGroup of your component.

I imagine you use ReactiveForms, so in yours components you can define

```
@ViewChild(FormGroupDirective,{static:true}) _form:NgForm
```

And use

```
  portalAttached(event:any){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      const form=event.instance?._form?.form
      if (form)
        form.statusChanges.pipe(
          startWith(form.status),
          map(x=>x=='VALID'?true:false)
        ).subscribe((res:any)=>{
          ..you received true if valid, or false if invalid or pendind or disabled
        })
    })
  }
```

I enclosed in a setTimeout to check the form after the attached is made it

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehqrvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-portal-overview-example.ts)

NOTE: In the stackblitz I interchange the "map" to return false if valid and true in the other cases to use a variable "disabled"